# What collapsible or compact skis should I get for commuting?

Tags: skiing, winter, cross-country-skiing

I want to be able to commute part way to school via skiing, but can't carry around full length skis all day. Has anyone heard of or used a good pair of compact cross country skis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only retail folding skis are from [Mountain Approach](http://www.mtnapproach.com/), and they are touring skis with skins permanently attached, so are more of a snowshoe than a ski, and only really for going uphill in the back country (you fold them up when you summit and then snowboard down).

As for short cross-country skis, there was a fad in the mid-late 90s when 145cm skis became popular for a bit, but I haven't seen anything like that in ages.